# Combining Bash Scripting and Java

Tags: java, bash, selenium, jar

So I've written a little selenium tool that goes to a url (myURL.com) and does a few things.  What I'd like to do is pass in myURL.com from the command line.

I already have it working so I can run:
java -jar myLittleApp.jar (this works and opens up firefox and does everything as expected)

I also have it working so that the jar asks the console for user input:

```
java -jar myLittleApp.jar
What url would you like to use?
<user input>
```

What I would like is to make it a one-liner, so something like:

```
java -jar myLittleApp.jar <user input>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code so we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

The command line arguments go to args in main:

```
static public void main (String[] args) {
    String url = args[0];
```